# Need to resolve and issue with HTTPServletRequest

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I currently trying to start up an intellij project connecting it to tomcat. I previously had the same project on a different machine and it worked fine, however in the global action its not allowing the import of javax.servlet.http.HTTPServletRequest;  and its saying it cannot resolve symbol http 
any ideas as to how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Tomcat [application server is configured](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/application-servers.html) and added to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) with the **Provided** scope.